# How can I toggle showing these two elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

So, I composed a quick jQuery function to give an idea of what I am looking for specifically, if anyone can help me solve this issue. I read a few posts on getting one element to hide while another shows. I don't have much experience on jQuery, so I apologize in advance. What I did find was that you can have both call simultaneously, or you could use the second statement as a callback. I'm really only looking for something that will toggle the displays of the two with a moderate fade. I have in mind that I don't want the triangles to move, it should be as if the text is just changing inside the triangle. But what I have here doesn't seem to be effective.
I want to have the second triangle hidden on page load, but I cannot get it to, and I also cannot get the first triangle to hide on click. I am just seeking a quick fix for the issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="button1"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="button2"><p>2</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Accompanied with the jQuery function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.button2').hide();
});
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('.button1').hide();
    $('.button2').show();
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
    $('.button2').hide();
    $('.button1').show();
});
```

With a bit of CSS:

```
.buttons{
    width:100%;
}
.buttons .container{
    text-align:center;
}
.button1, .button2{
    display:inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:40px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid transparent;
    border-top:40px solid #CC0000;
    cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;
}
.button1 p, .button2 p{
    position:absolute;
    color:#F9F9F9;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    font-size:7px;
}
```

and here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cWH3/3/) if anyone would like to change anything.

Comment: The CSS in your Fiddle missed a dot before `button2` and jQuery is not being loaded

Comment: The CSS in your **JSFiddle** should be : `.button1, .button2{...}` instead of `.button1, button2{...}` ! You don't need to change anything to your code except that !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use jquery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cWH3/6/

```
$('.button1,.button2').click(function(){
    $('.button1,.button2').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this :

```
$('.button1,.button2').click(function(){
    $('.button1').toggle();
    $('.button2').toggle();
});
```

Firstly you can listen on multiple elements and secondly - the `.toggle()` function will show / hide for you depending on current state

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cWH3/5/)

Note: the CSS was missing a `.` before `button2` and you need to select a library (ie jQuery)

Comment: thank you. I did happen to add in that . after I noticed it wasn't there. I did not copy and paste the code. I hand typed it when I posted the original question. Thank you so much for that. I really appreciate it. Works perfectly. I also have jQuery called on the actual website, but didn't include it here

Comment: I have the code exactly as it is in the jsfiddle. It hides the second triangle, but does not toggle between them. I have jQuery 1.10.1 loaded from Google APIs. I'm just really confused with this whole concept. I feel like it's probably the smallest typo ever that I keep missing..

Comment: Final comment. I guess jQuery location really does matter in html... Moved it just below the div "buttons" from the original and all seems to be working outstandingly. Thank you, sir

Comment: @user2508857 if you wrap the binding to the click event in a ready handler - the code is executed when the DOM is ready .. your alternative is to have the code at the bottom of the page. I always use the ready handler for clarity

Answer (score 1):

with some fade effect:

```
$('.button1,.button2').click(function(){
    $('.button1,.button2').filter(':visible').fadeToggle({
       done: function(){
            $(this).siblings().fadeToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: haha that was freaking beautiful, man. Adds such a great touch. Went ahead with this one because it was just so amazing. All of the comments on here were amazing. The animation is great

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**You code works fine!** (Even if it's not optimized)

**Note**: Don't forget to include ***jQuery*** !

There is a missing **dot** in your **CSS**:

### CSS

```
.button1, button2{
    display:inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:40px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid transparent;
    border-top:40px solid #CC0000;
    cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;
}
```

Should start with `.button1 .button2` ! There's a missing dot before **button2**.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/4cWH3/8/)

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle. Adding the . only made the second triangle appear from behind the first. Should I have included the library IN the jsfiddle?

Comment: @user2508857 Yes, you can [**see how here**](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions). The `Framework and Extensions` part of the page is on the top left of the screen. You can select your jQuery version where it says **No Library (Pure JS)**

Comment: awesome. thanks for letting me know. I'll be sure to include that next time.

Comment: @user2508857 No problem! It's the easiest things people tend to forget (and then struggle for hours trying to figure out why nothing's working) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6ftL/3/)

May this would help

```
var toggleButtons = function() {
 $('.button2,.button1').toggle();
} 

$('.button1,.button2'').click(function(){
   toggleButtons();
});
```

Comment: toggleButtons(); => $(this).toggle();